# round robin id generator in C

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I am trying to code up a small operating system and I have 100 processes that need to have unique process IDs generated automatically. they have to be generated sequentially in a round-robin fashion.
Is there any algorithm for this? Any help? Thank you.

Comment: I think the generally accepted algorithm for sequential numbers is to add 1 to the last number you remember generating.... :)

Comment: And if you want the numbers to wrap around every N, `id = ++id % N` is the typical approach.

Comment: thanks, can you explain the wrap around if you don't mind?

Comment: @Jon: I don't think there is a sequence point in the expression `id = ++id % N`. I like `id = (id + 1) % N` better.

Comment: @biz: Think of the modulus operator `%` as "casting out" multiples of its second operand. For example, `x % 100` will always be a number in the range `[0, 99]` (assuming `x` is positive).

Comment: @pmg: I believe that `id = ++id % N` is safe because incrementing `id` needs to be done before the mod (pre-increment operator says so), which needs to be done before storing back to `id`. If it were `id = id++ % N` then there might be a problem.

Comment: @Jon: no. `++id` has a value and a side-effect. The value needs to be calculated before being used, but the side-effect can be postponed to some time before the next sequence-point.

Comment: @pmg: I 'll have to agree to that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The real "problem" is if you need to stop processes and start new ones. In that case, simply wrapping around is not enough. You need a way to not generate a process id that's already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an array with 100 elements (initialized to 0) and manage that

```
int array[100] = {0};
```

---

```
/* kill process N */
void killprocess(int N) {
    array[N] = 0;
}
```

---

```
/* add process N */
void addprocess(int N) {
    array[N] = 1;
}
```

---

```
/* find free process starting with N */
int findfreeprocess(int N) {
    int k, ndx;
    for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        ndx = (N + k) % 100;
        if (array[ndx] == 0) return ndx;
    }
    return -1; /* indicate no free process */
}
```

Comment: I don't get the third part :s can you explain further?

Comment: It assumes the array is a circular buffer and searches for a zero element starting with N, "going back" to 0 once it reaches 99. If all elements are different than 0, return -1 to indicate just that.